# SQLQuery list cast exception after update hibernate 3 to hibernate 5

Tags: java, hibernate

SQLQuery list cast exception after update hibernate 3 to hibernate 5. This is my code

```
public List<List<String>> getReportQuery(String query) {

    Session sess = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    final List<List<String>> table = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    sess.beginTransaction();

    SQLQuery it = sess.createSQLQuery(query);

    table.add(it.list());
    return table;
}
```

The same code works in hibernate 3 but not in Hibernate 5, I tried to cast it to String like,

```
List<String> res = it.list();
    for(String s : res){
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add(s);
        table.add(temp);
    }
}
```

But same exception occur,

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding `it.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);` to my query instance.
This will convert the result set as map

Working code,

```
public List<List<String>> getReportQuery(String query) {

        Session sess = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        final List<List<String>> table = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        sess.beginTransaction();

        SQLQuery it = sess.createSQLQuery(query);
        it.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
        List<Map<String,Object>> result = it.list();

        for(Map<String,Object> k : result){
            final List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Entry<String,Object> entry : k.entrySet())
                tmp.add(entry.getValue() != null ? entry.getValue().toString() : null);

            table.add(tmp);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to using 'createSQLQuery()' method which is now deprecated from hibernate 5.2. Check [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery).

I had a similar exception when we upgraded from hibernate 5.0 to hibernate 5.2, see stack trace below for more details. My test cases stopped working with these exceptions. Once I replaced the deprecated methods with the latest ones, it started working again.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to java.util.Date
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.unwrap(JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor.java:24) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimestampTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(TimestampTypeDescriptor.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.bindNamedParameters(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1575) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1504) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```